# How to enable offline cpu in qemu?

Tags: kernel, virtualization, cpu, qemu, offline

I am using qemu to run ubuntu16. I met `offline cpu`. I want to enable it. However, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0` is not found. How to enable it?

Thanks very much.

```bsh
~$lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Off-line CPU(s) list:  4-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             4
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Ubuntu has used *yy* based releases to mean *snap* only releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 16 which is supported until 2026), but I've taken your question as being about a 16.04 system, which is now only on-topic on this site if your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.   There is no Ubuntu 16, so if you meant Ubuntu Core 16 you should say so.